# insert foreach result values as multiple rows in laravel

Tags: laravel

My foreach result has 2 values cust_pack_waste_id and cust_pack_quantity.I want to insert this values as multiple row in db.
i am uploading a db image below how i want to insert the datas,

[![cust_pack_waste_id ,cust_pack_quantity]need to be changed others are same

```
  $waste=DB::table('tbl_waste_items')
  ->get();

 if(count($waste)>0)
 {
  foreach($waste as $wastes)
   {
    $waste_id=$wastes->waste_items_id;
    $quantity=$wastes->waste_items_bag;

    
    $chk=DB::table('tbl_customer_package_details')
    ->where('cust_pack_customer_id',$customer_id)
 
    ->first();
    
    if($chk)
    {
        
      
        echo "display";
    }
    else{
        
       
        
        $data=array('cust_pack_customer_id'=>$customer_id,'cust_pack_waste_id'=>$waste_id,'cust_pack_quantity'=>$quantity,'cust_pack_user_id'=>$type);
        
      $ff= DB::table('tbl_customer_package_details')
       ->insert($data);
```

Comment: And what is your question/problem?

Comment: in my case only one row is inserted instead of 4 rows

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to insert multiple `$data` rows into database. So you could:

```
     $data[]=array('cust_pack_customer_id'=>$customer_id, 
                   'cust_pack_waste_id'=>$waste_id, 
                   'cust_pack_quantity'=>$quantity, 
                   'cust_pack_user_id'=>$type);
  }  // end of for-each loop

  $ff= DB::table('tbl_customer_package_details')->insert($data);
```

Comment: i tried this,but it insert only one row.i have 4 rows

Comment: You should make sure you have used `$data[]` and you could also `dd($data)` after the foreach loop to check.

Comment: still insert only one row

Comment: What's the output of `dd($data)` , one row or four rows?

Comment: Then you should check the for-each loop.